# Place sensitive information such as database login in a separate file?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu, configuration

Currently it's in application.ini but it gets passed around to all developers because it's included in a version control. It's bad security wise. I want to place it in a separate file called `db.keys` outside `www` directory. I'd like to solicit ideas about how to do this. The question that came to mind is:

How do I parse the the `.keys` file and make it available for my app?

We're using Zend Framework 1.12 on Ubuntu server. I understand that there's a function called `parse_ini_file` which can be used to parse `.ini` files but what should I use for files with custom extension?

Comment: Putting it [below the web root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550471/php-include-file-in-webroot-from-file-outside-webroot) is a good idea. Do you have any encryption options available? I know that NuSphere has [NuCoder](http://www.nusphere.com/products/index.htm) for instance which encrypts all the php files.

Comment: @Revent: We don't have it as of the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Config_Ini` is just a wrapper for `parse_ini_file`. If your `db.keys` has a valid `INI` format `parse_ini_file` should be able to parse it.

To merge multiple configs use `merge` method:

```
$config  = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/application.ini','staging');
$config2 = new Zend_Config_Ini('/www/db.keys','staging');
$config->merge($config2);
```