# Run an Html file in Apache Server from outside web root

Tags: php, apache

I have a folder which contain HTML, CSS, JS, image files across various folders. For security reasons I want to place it outside the web root.

I have come across a solution using `file_get_contents` function of PHP.

But then there is a problem with hyper-linking present in the page. For example, the link to the javascript file in the page:

```
<script src="lms/APIConstants.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

searches for the file in `http://localhost/lms/APIConstants.js` and returns an error of

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/lms/APIConstants.js
```

I am aware of using .htaccess file for hiding some folders from the web root. I am looking for some other insightful solution.

Comment: Then make it a full url

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550471/php-include-file-in-webroot-from-file-outside-webroot

Comment: I can't do that, this HTML,CSS,JS files are auto generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this.. Might be helpful for others.

Steps that were followed:

- Use a separate file for reading from outside web root (*say filereader.php*).
- Call this file with URL encoding the local file path. http://localhost.ca/lms/filereader.php/path/to/local/file.html
- Parse the URL to get the path - `/path/to/local/file.html`
- Apply PHP's `readfile()` function to read from the obtained path.

Doing this, all the hyperlinks in `file.html` gets loaded from the following path.

> http://localhost.ca/lms/filereader.php/path/to/local/

The mime-type for each file has to be defined. Also a proper http response code is to be thrown using PHP's `http_response_code()` when a file is not found.

**Note:** You might need to enable `AcceptPathInfo` in the Apache configuration.

Comment: Make sure only certain files are readable from the filereader. Otherwise, a simple get request can be used to read files such as logs and that can be a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

when you include a file then code/script runs according to new path on which it is being included.

It finds the APIConstants.js file into the folder **Ims** which is in root directory.
but actually it is outside the root directory.

So give the path like this.. If Ims folder is one step down to the root directory.

```
src="../lms/APIConstants.js"
```